# get unused AMIs using boto3 witn AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to get the list of all unused AMIs using boto3.

### creating variables

```
import boto3

REGION = 'us-east-1'
OWNER_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', REGION)
ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2', REGION)
```

### get AMIs ID by instances

```
def get_used_amis_by_instances():

    reservations = ec2_client.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'owner-id',
            'Values': [
                OWNER_ID,
            ]
        },
    ])['Reservations']
    amis_used_list = []
    for reservation in reservations:
        ec2_instances = reservation['Instances']
        for ec2 in ec2_instances:
            ImageId = ec2['ImageId']
            if ImageId not in amis_used_list:
                amis_used_list = amis_used_list + [ImageId]
    return amis_used_list
```

### get the all AMIs ID

I just need the list of AMIs ID

```
def get_all_amis():
    amis = ec2_resource.images.filter(Owners = [OWNER_ID])
    all_amis = []
    for ami in amis.all():
        if ami.id not in all_amis:
            all_amis = all_amis + [ami.id]
    return all_amis
```

### get unused AMIs.

Using the previous methods I have the all_amis and all_used_amis.

```
def get_unused_amis(all_amis, all_used_amis):

    unused_amis_list = []
    for ami_id in all_amis:
        if ami_id not in all_used_amis:
            if ami_id not in unused_amis_list:
                unused_amis_list = unused_amis_list + [ami_id]
    return unused_amis_list
```

### Output the results

```
def deregister_amis(event, context):

    all_amis = get_all_amis()
    print("All AMIs: %d" % len(all_amis) )

    all_used = get_used_amis_by_instances()
    print("All used AMIs: %d" % len(all_used) )

    all_unused = get_unused_amis(all_amis, all_used)
    print("All unused AMIs: %d" % len(all_unused) )
```

### My problem

The `deregister_amis` is returning

- **All AMIs**: 201
- **All used AMIs**: 102
- **All unused AMIs**: 140

I expect 99 for all unused AMIs. I don't see where is my error. But I don't see if there is maybe an error with the used value of 102. The total is correct 201, but with the other two values maybe I am doing something wrong or missing something. Let me know if you are able to see where is my error because I can.

Comment: Do you have any Instances using Public Images or Images not owned by `OWNER_ID`?

Comment: @franklinsijo, I am using in both cases the filter by OWNERID. Do I need to specify any other filter?

Comment: The filter applied in `describe_instances` filters the instances owned by `OWNER_ID`. Add an additional check to verify whether the owner of Image is `OWNER_ID`.

Comment: OMG. Really I was checking only the instances but I forgot to check if the **ImageId** is also owned by us. Ohh this was blowing my mind.. maybe because I did this work really late last night. Thank you @franklinsijo

Comment: @franklinsijo but something is pretty sure. We are not using 140 of 201 AMIs owned by us. That is real.

Answer (score 2):

One AMI can be used by many instance. Using list, you might get same AMI added into the list(where multiple instance using there same AMI). Your list is alright if you want number of instances running, but not AMI.

You should use set() in the first place, not list.  Just convert all your list to set().  In addition, using set, you can do subtraction, unison,etc. So you really don't need the redundant get_unused_amis() function.

It is so simple using the set

```
unused_ami = all_amis - all_used_amis
```

quick hack

```
def deregister_amis(event, context):

    all_amis = set(get_all_amis())
    print("All AMIs: %d" % len(all_amis) )

    all_used = set(get_used_amis_by_instances())
    print("All used AMIs: %d" % len(all_used) )

    all_unused = all_amis - all_used 
    print("All unused AMIs: %d" % len(all_unused) )
```

After another view, I think using the quick hack is better. Retaining the list give you one extra advantage : You can check out how many AMI is used more than once.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I removed my redundant ```get_unused_amis()``` method and used your code.

Comment: @Robert : just update my opinion. The quick hack should be fined. List will give you extra info when you do `get_used_amis_by_instances()`. However, get_all_amis() using a list is not useful, since AMI-id should be unique.